# How to find the expression for Vout?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, voltage-source

I have that circuit and I need the equation of Vo, I've been told that I can solve it by the Kirchhoff method but I'm not sure. [image: circuit]
[image: kirchhoff]

Is there a way that the expression looks like Vo=K(V2-V1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opamp circuits like this can be solved with a few assumptions:

1) The circuit is linear and therefore superposition holds.  This means you can solve for the output in terms of one input at a time, with the other input at zero (volts, in this case).

2) The opamp is ideal and therefore has infinite gain.  This means a) the - input is driven to be equal to the + input by the negative feedback loop around the opamp (formed here by R2 and R1), and b) the input impedance is infinite, so no current flows into the opamp + or - terminals.

Solving this circuit:

First set V2=0.  You'll find Vo = -R2/R1*V1.  Why? The current flowing from the output to the - node must equal the current flowing from the - node to the input source V1 (by KCL and Rin+ being infinite).  And V+ = V- = 0V since we assumed V2=0 and V+=V-.

(Vo - 0V)/R2 = (0V - V1)/R1, solve for Vo:

Vo = -R2/R1*V1

Second set V1=0.  You'll find Vo = R4/(R3+R4)*(1+R2/R1)*V2.  Why?  VA= R4/(R3+R4)*V2. V-=V+=VA.  Then use KCL as above,

(Vo - VA)/R2 = (VA - 0V)/R1, solve for Vo:

Vo = VA*(1+R2/R1) = R4/(R3+R4)*(1+R2/R1)*V2

From superposition, we can sum these two for the total output from both input sources:

Vo = -R2/R1*V1 + R4/(R3+R4)*(1+R2/R1)*V2

Also, you'll recognize these as the equations for the "standard" inverting and non-inverting op-amp circuit gains:

Vo = -R2/R1*Vin (same as V1 above)

Vo = (1+R2/R1)*V+ (no voltage divider, directly driving V+).

Comment: Is there a way that the expression looks like Vo=K(V2-V1) ?

Comment: @agustin- Rearrange the Vo expression:  Vo = R4/(R3+R4)*(1+R2/R1)*V2 - (R2/R1)*V1.  Then in order to have K(V2-V1), the coefficients of V2 and V1 must be equal.  In other words, set the resistor values such that:  R4/(R3+R4)*(1+R2/R1)=R2/R1.  One option:  set R3=R4 and R2=R1, then you have 1/2*(1+1)=1.

Answer (score 3):

In your lower schema, you are putting a wire between the + and - inputs of the op-amp: This is wrong. There is no \$i_3\$ current, and no current into the op-amp inputs.

Just write down the equations:

- \$V_{A+} = \dfrac{V_2 \times R_4}{R_3 + R_4}\$
- \$\dfrac{V_1 - V_{A-}}{R_1} = - \dfrac{V_O - V_{A-}} {R_2}\$
- \$V_{A+} = V_{A-}\$ (condition for the amplifier to be in linear mode)

Rearrange a bit... et voilà!

Comment: With an ideal op-amp, the wire would be irrelevant, because the voltages at the two inputs would be identical, and thus i3 would be 0. It does make the analysis not work, though.

Comment: Is there a way that the expression looks like Vo=K(V2-V1) ?

Comment: I don't think the wire is okay even with an ideal op amp. Op amp circuits use negative feedback from the output to make the input voltages equal. If the inputs are shorted, the output voltage is irrelevant, and would ideally be zero volts.

Comment: @AdamHaun - If you consider the wire as an infinitely low resistance, it is irrelevant because with an ideal op-amp you have infinite gain, so the voltage across the wire is 0V. Of course, ideal op-amps cannot exist, so it would be a problem in any real circumstances.

Comment: An ideal op amp has infinite gain, but it's still differential gain. The negative feedback normally restricts it to one stable state. If you add a wire between the inputs, there are an infinite number of stable states, because any output voltage produces a 0 V differential.

Comment: Keep in mind that voltage is only half of the picture here. From a current standpoint, adding a wire alters the behavior of the R3/R4 voltage divider.